# Calculating total amount of cycles over threads

Tags: java, multithreading

From my main thread I start 20 threads. I each thread I do (for example) 5 iterations. How do I calculate the value of the cycles. In other words I want the to be consecutively numbered. Calculation happens inside of the thread. (It is aware of it's number.) I later want to be able to say something like "Error happened in cycle No. 127"

So to speak I am looking for the formula of how to calculate this.

Thank you very much!

```
Example:
Thread: 0 Iteration 0 = Cycle 1
Thread: 0 Iteration 1 = Cycle 2
Thread: 0 Iteration 2 = Cycle 3
Thread: 0 Iteration 3 = Cycle 4
Thread: 0 Iteration 4 = Cycle 5
Thread: 1 Iteration 0 = Cycle 6
Thread: 1 Iteration 1 = Cycle 7
Thread: 1 Iteration 2 = Cycle 8
Thread: 1 Iteration 3 = Cycle 9
Thread: 1 Iteration 4 = Cycle 10
Thread: 2 Iteration 0 = Cycle 11
...
Thread: 9 Iteration 0 = Cycle 46
Thread: 9 Iteration 1 = Cycle 47
Thread: 9 Iteration 2 = Cycle 48
Thread: 9 Iteration 3 = Cycle 49
Thread: 9 Iteration 4 = Cycle 50
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an AtomicInteger. It's a thread safe implementation of int, so every thread can access it and count the iterations.